# Check user is valid windows authentication MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an application which users Windows authentication in conjuction with ASPnet roles, so roles stored in a database but users on the windows domain.

I want to have a management page where admins add existing users to roles, does anyone know of a simple way I can check that the username input is valid in the active directory domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [PrincipalContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.aspx) class:

```
public bool UserExistsInAd(string username)
{
    using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        var up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
        return up != null;
    }
}
```

Obviously the account you have configured your ASP.NET MVC 3 application to run under in IIS must have sufficient privileges to access the Active Drectory.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145037.aspx) namespace